# Cat sinus infection? What should I tell sitter to look out for?

Tags: cats, health

Cat is 4 year old, spayed female, domestic longhair, calico, part Angora. She had evidence of a past FHV infection (antibodies present), probably from before when I found her as a 4 week old kitten. History of goopy eyes, snoring, and a small infrequent lesion that appears above her left eye, presumably due to previous FHV damage to sinuses and tear ducts.

For the past 4 days she has developed:

- Clear watery discharge from right eye and increased closure of that eye. Eye itself does not appear irritated.
- Clear watery nasal discharge.
- Sneezing (messy, and apparently she gets great pleasure out of sneezing directly into my face).
- Clear watery drooling.
- Occasional wheeze (but normal breathing rate and does not appear to have breathing difficulty) even while awake.

No other symptoms present, no behavioral/eating/drinking/elimination changes, no other known health issues, no "traditional" diseases (FIV and such).

The other cat in the house has no issues.

It is winter, *very* cold outside, and *very* dry inside. I'm thinking either the dry air is irritating her sinuses or perhaps she has a sinus infection (although I've never experienced a cat with a cold).

My question is: I'm about to go out of town for a week on an emergency work trip, otherwise I'd take her to the vet tomorrow. What could be going on and *what should I tell the cat sitter to look out for* in case she needs an emergency trip to the vet?